# How to iterate values from mutiple arrays of object and patch values to new response Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

I am getting below data from api response

```
const apiResponse = {
    "factoryId": "A_0421",
    "loss": [
        {
            "lossType": "Planned Stoppage Time",
            "duration": "1111"
        },
        {
            "lossType": "Quality Time",
            "duration": "2222"
        }
    ],
    "break": [
        {
            "lossType": "Format",
            "duration": "5.749999",
            "eventCount": "2"
        }
    ],
    "kpi": [
        {
            "mpl": "16556.598475000053"
        }
    ]
};
```

I want code which check above api response have loss,break and kpi array is present or not
and than find the value from above arrays and map value into below formfield.

**I tried below code but i am not able to access all arrays object.**

Can anyone please help me iterate and patch all values in a efficient way.

```
prepareFormForImport(resp) {
      for (let element of resp) {
        return {
        factoryId: null,
          availableTime: {
            bankHoliday: element.loss.lossType === 'Bank Holidays' ? element.duration : 0,
            breakDownTime: element.loss.lossType === 'Quality Time' ? element.duration : 0
            },
            operatingTime: {
                maintenanceTime: element.break.lossType === 'Format' ? element.duration : 0
            },
            uom: element.kpi === 'mpl' ? element.mpl : 0
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try like this?

```
  finalpayload: any[] = [
    {
      factoryId: null,
      availableTime: {
        bankHoliday: null,
        breakDownTime: null,
      },
      operatingTime: {
        maintenanceTime: null,
      },
      uom: null,
    }
  ];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // Simulate the API response
    const apiResponse = {
      factoryId: "A_0421",
      loss: [
        {
          lossType: "Planned Stoppage Time",
          duration: "1111"
        },
        {
          lossType: "Quality Time",
          duration: "2222"
        }
      ],
      break: [
        {
          lossType: "Format",
          duration: "5.749999",
          eventCount: "2"
        }
      ],
      kpi: [
        {
          mpl: "16556.598475000053"
        }
      ]
    };

    // Map data from API response to finalpayload
    this.mapData(apiResponse);
  }

  private mapData(apiResponse: any): void {
    if (apiResponse.loss && Array.isArray(apiResponse.loss)) {
      apiResponse.loss.forEach((item: any) => {
        switch (item.lossType) {
          case "Planned Stoppage Time":
            this.finalpayload[0].availableTime.bankHoliday = item.duration;
            break;
          case "Quality Time":
            this.finalpayload[0].availableTime.breakDownTime = item.duration;
            break;
        }
      });
    }

    if (apiResponse.break && Array.isArray(apiResponse.break)) {
      apiResponse.break.forEach((item: any) => {
        if (item.lossType === "Format") {
          this.finalpayload[0].operatingTime.maintenanceTime = item.duration;
        }
      });
    }

    if (apiResponse.kpi && Array.isArray(apiResponse.kpi)) {
      apiResponse.kpi.forEach((item: any) => {
        if (item.mpl) {
          this.finalpayload[0].uom = item.mpl;
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thnks for your logic, but is it possible to prepare formFields inside mapData function only, i dont want to write seprate this.finalPayload and assign values to it.

Comment: Can you please check my function prepareFormForImport which i tried, Same approach i am expecting with api response mapped to each field and return data..

Comment: @Shilpa you can rename the function and at the end of function you can return the data and assign it to your variable

Comment: Can you plz modify your code, i didnt get what you are asking to do..Please do it

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer to your question @Shilpa

```js
//variables
let bankHoliday = '';
let breakDownTime = '';
let maintenanceTime = '';
let uom = '';

//Function to extract data from JSON
function getData(data) {
//since apiResponse is JSON, parse it into an object.
  let object = JSON.parse(data);
//The object must have the loss, break and kpi property
  if(Object.hasOwn(object,'loss') && Object.hasOwn(object, 'break') && Object.hasOwn(object, 'kpi')) {
    
//We are using Number.parseFloat() to convert into number.
    object.loss.forEach((obj) => {
      if(obj.lossType === 'Bank Holidays') {
        bankHoliday = Number.parseFloat(obj.duration);
        }
      
      if(obj.lossType === 'Quality Time') {
        breakDownTime = Number.parseFloat(obj.duration);
        }
      });
    
    object.break.forEach((obj) => {
      if(obj.lossType === 'Format') {
        maintenanceTime = Number.parseFloat(obj.duration);
        }
      });
    
    object.kpi.forEach((obj) => {
      if(Object.hasOwn(obj, 'mpl')) {
        uom = Number.parseFloat(obj.mpl);
        }
      });
    
    
    }
   
  }


const apiResponse = '{"factoryId": "A_04","loss": [{"lossType": "Bank Holidays","duration": "1111"},{"lossType": "Quality Time","duration":"2222"}],"break": [{"lossType": "Format","duration": "5.749999","eventCount": "2"}],"kpi": [{"mpl": "16556.598475000053"}]}'
          
  function prepareFormForImport(apiResponse) {
  //run the getData() function on the apiResponse
  getData(apiResponse);
  
      if(bankHoliday !== '' && breakDownTime !== '' && maintenanceTime !== '' && uom !== '') {
        return {
        factoryId: null,
          availableTime: {
            bankHoliday: bankHoliday,
            breakDownTime: breakDownTime,
            },
            operatingTime: {
                maintenanceTime: maintenanceTime,
            },
            uom: uom,
        }
   
    }
}
```

Comment: @Shilpa if you are using the code block above, please ensure your apiResponse is a JSON string